# Maximum length of text fields in shapefile and geodatabase formats?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, fields-attributes, limitations

The maximum text string for a field in a geodatabase is 320 characters.

The data I am importing has long character strings and it seems to be truncating when I convert into shapefile at the max text string and messing the fields up.

Is there a way to extend this to 700-1000 characters?

Answer (score 30):

The shapefile maximum field width is 254. It is a limitation 
of the dBase format.

File geodatabase text fields are unlimited in length (2^31-1)
and enterprise geodatabases are limited by 
their underlying RDBMS for VARCHAR and NVARCHAR width.

The only way to work around the dBase width limitation is to not use shapefiles.

If you must use shapefile then you'd need to make multiple fields and concatenate them later (but be careful -- since dBase also has a 4000 byte record limit, you could run out of space quickly).

Answer (score 18):

> ### File geodatabase size and name limits
>
> […]
>   **File geodatabase size:** No limit
>   **Table or feature class size:** 1 TB (default), 4 GB or 256 TB with keyword
>   **Number of feature classes and tables:** 2,147,483,647
>   **Number of fields in a feature class or table:** 65,534
>   **Number of rows in a feature class or table:** 2,147,483,647
>   **Geodatabase name length:** Number of characters the operating system allows in a folder name
>   **Feature class or table name length:** 160 characters
>   **Field name length:** 64 characters
>   **Text field width:** 2,147,483,647

see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018s00000002000000