# Error 001156. increasing the length of text limit

Tags: arcgis-desktop, excel, arccatalog, personal-geodatabase, error-001156

I'm fairly new to ArcGIS for Desktop and i want to import my excel table to my personal gdb but i end up getting an [error code:001156](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00vp00000029001156) and my import fails.

I soon found out that it was the lengthy structural descriptions in my table.

Is there anyway that I can increase the text cap within ArcCatalog.

im not really good with Python either.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the maximum field length for a Personal Geodatabase text field is 255 characters.

For a File Geodatabase the same limit appears to be 2,147,483,647 (see [Maximimum length of text fields in shapefile and geodatabase formats?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75092/esri-text-string-field-max)).

For this and many other reasons [I prefer to always use File Geodatabases rather than Personal Geodatabases](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60196/whether-to-use-file-geodatabase-gdb-personal-geodatabase-mdb-or-shapefi/60198#60198).

I recommend that you create a File Geodatabase by right-clicking on a folder in the Catalog window of ArcMap (or in ArcCatalog), or by using the [Create File GDB (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000pw000000) tool.