# Viewing/displaying fields with high character lengths in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, file-geodatabase, excel

I am trying to import an Excel spreadsheet with a field that has more than 255 characters.

Do I have to convert the Excel table to a file geodatabase table first in order to view this field in ArcMap?

How can I view this field in ArcMap without using a hyperlink to the Excel table and without writing a script?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is here... do you have a large field in Excel and want that imported into a geodatabase or is it that you want to export your feature class into an excel table? Is the data spatial or not (just a table)? Can you expand a little more on what you have and what you want to achieve please.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?  Additional Excel support came in at around 10.2.1 I think.  When you say "geodatabase" do you mean a file geodatabase (*.gdb) or another flavour?

Comment: You don't really use a geodatabase to "view" fields, regardless of width, and certainly not in files of other formats.  Geodatabases *store* data.  You'd need to transfer the data, then choose a client to view it.

Comment: I have edited the question for better understanding ,

Comment: Related, and possibly duplicate as originally worded: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75092/ This sounds like a display issue in the attribute table. You may want to check the help files, particularly related to table display options and setting widths, heights, and wrap. See http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000003n000000 for starters.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using a recent version of ArcGIS for Desktop, and I have not tested, but you should be able to use the [Excel To Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/excel-to-table.htm) tool to do this:

> Converts Microsoft Excel files into a table.

I frequently use fields of 4,000 characters in file geodatabase tables and feature classes.

Comment: 4000 characters for a field name? :) How come you really need them to be so long? ;)

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Of course not - 4,000 is field length not the length of the field name :-)

Comment: Ah my bad :) was thinking of the name length :) it makes sense now.

Comment: It showed the lengthy field. However , it cuts off some of the words.. y is that? Is the text suppose to word wrapped before importation? i did not word-wrap the text.