# Does joining CSV file to shapefile overcomes the 255 character limitation of shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, attribute-joins

I have a CSV file in which some fields contain values greater than 255 characters. I want to ask that wether joining the CSV file with a shapefile overcomes the 255 character limitation of shapefile and displays the data in CSV completely.
If not, then what is the solution for it?

Comment: It's not going to work, use a feature class instead of a shapefile.

Comment: You have a tag for [tag:arcgis] but make no mention in your question body or title about the GIS software that you are using. Is it ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: Have you ever tried it? I would love to hear your answer...

Comment: I did a quick test for this on QGIS 2.10.1. The shapefile can **display** more than 255 characters (since the data itself is coming from the .csv file). But if you re-save this shapefile, with the joined data, as a new shapefile, the maximum number of characters is 254 (strangely not 255 for me).

Comment: 254 is the correct [limit to string field width](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75092/maximimum-length-of-text-fields-in-shapefile-and-geodatabase-formats) in a shapefile (the [dBase III+ character field limit](http://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/format/data_types.html) ).

Comment: @Joseph..@Vince..yea thats my problem..it simpy cuits out the rest of words. whats the workaround?

Comment: @Rehan - If you just want to display the data, leave your shapefile joined with the csv.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Vince:

> 254 is the correct [limit to string field
>   width](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75092/maximimum-length-of-text-fields-in-shapefile-and-geodatabase-formats)
>   in a shapefile (the [dBase III+ character field
>   limit](http://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/format/data_types.html)
>   ).

To workaround the this limit you will either need to

> leave your shapefile joined with the csv

as suggested by @Joseph, assuming that displaying it is all you need to do.

However, if you need to store the more than 254 character field in a feature class then I think using a file geodatabase (as suggested by @GISGe) instead of a shapefile will be your best option.