# What characters are not acceptable in an ArcGIS text field (File Geodatabase)?

Tags: file-geodatabase, attribute-joins, fields-attributes, text

Trying to join a table to my feature and it keeps leaving out a field. The field is a legal description of a property, it has all sorts of ***funky*** characters:

- :
- ;
- /
- \
- ()
- '
- "
- and more

The field is also long, from 100 to 1500 characters, but based on this I should be ok for field length: **[Maximum length of text fields in shapefile and geodatabase formats?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75092/maximimum-length-of-text-fields-in-shapefile-and-geodatabase-formats)**

I can't find any documentation regarding what can or cannot be entered here. I assume its only Unicode or ASCII values, but I've removed pretty much everything and am still having the join error. The join error, doesn't show up in the join, it just excludes the field in the join.

Comment: File geodatabase is Unicode. You can't load extended ASCII codesets -- they must be converted at load time. Bizzare row contents might not match due to real differences. You'd need to dump the actual bytestream to do such a comparison.

Comment: @Vince Ok, i kind of figured something like that. I've been trying to find an excel formula or something that can convert to Unicode, but haven't yet. Any links?

Comment: If the "table" isn't a table, and is instead a CSV or XLS*  file, then the problem statement needs editing, to remove the focus from join to manifestation of the file as a table. I do not let Excel anywhere near my GIS data, so I'm the last person to ask about formulae (though I wrote some C source for UTF-8/UTF-16 conversion that's in the geodatabase codebase)

Comment: @Vince yeah, I've back tracked from excel back to its original CSV format and am using python to parse it. Taking some time (20,000 records) in three CSV's, but I think this will work long term once I get it up and running.

Comment: @Vince please add your comment as an answer, it definitely helped me!